# Are there no rules for naam jap?

Tags: rituals, nama-japa

I heard that one can do it anytime and with any activity.. Even while walking or lying on bed. Just want to know if its true?

Answer (score 0):

The intention behind any japa including naama japa is to bring a single pointedness or concentration of the mind.

Concentration of the mind is one of the most difficult things to achieve, but it's the most crucial for both worldly and spiritual goals. Left to itself, the mind prefers wandering and thinking about random things.

Hence for a **beginner spiritual seeker**, a proper quiet place, comfortable sitting position, time of the day etc are suggested (as per Patanjali's yoga sutras). This is so that all distractions due to oneself (knee joint pain, sleepiness etc) and due to others (noise, disturbance etc) are eliminated as much as possible.

However, as one gains sufficient concentration and the power to stay focused, the person may choose to do the japa at their own convenience.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).